Does $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \sin(2^k x)$ converge or is it bounded?
Does the following sum converge or have a maximum value?
$$S = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \sin(2^k x)$$
Context etc:
I know that similar sum with Sine replaced by Cosine diverges, since it is trivial to see that at $x=0$, all the cosines add a value of $1$ and it will blow up. With Sine, it is not so clear to me. I tried finding the maximum values for sums from $n=0$ to $n=50$ in Mathematica (using NMaximize since Maximize was choking beyond $n=8$) and I see that it doesn't monotonically increase or decrease. So likely there is no convergence. But I can't tell if it will blow up or if there is a maximum value (so far $n=40$ had the highest value).





For $x=2\pi/7$, the sum is
$$
S=\sin(2\pi/7)+\sin(4\pi/7)+\sin(8\pi/7)+ \sin(2\pi/7)+\sin(4\pi/7)+\sin(8\pi/7)+\cdots,
$$
which clearly diverges.
More generally, if $x=\frac{k\pi}{2^n}$ where $n$ is a natural number and $k$ an integer then the sum converges (a periodicity similar to the above is observed).

Nice reasoning. Are there other values at which blowup happens?

I was looking at $x=2\pi/n$, so all that matters is $2^k \mod n$. All I had to do was find an $n$ such that the classes generated by powers of $2$ do not come in pairs with opposite signs. For example, if $n=5$, then the powers of $2$ are $1,2,-1,-2$ modulo $5$, so they can pair up and cancel in the sum. But this doesn’t happen for $n=7$. I don’t have a complete understanding of the values of $n$ for which this happens.

One obvious restriction is that $2$ shouldn’t be a primitive root modulo $n$. That excludes $n=3,5$, but not $n=7$, for instance.
